# How can we configure Near Expiry Event time in Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, secret-key

I'm planning to customize the Near Expiry EventTime in Azure key vault.
I've gone through this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/tutorial-rotation-dual

In the above article , it has been mentioned that **30 days** before the expiration date of a secret, Key Vault publishes the "near expiry" event to Event Grid.

Is there any possibility that key vault publishes the near expiry event **10 days** before the expiration date of a secret ? If so , how can we customize it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you could not customize the near expiry time. In the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-key-vault), the **Secret Near Expiry** event will be triggered when the current version of a secret is about to expire. (The event is triggered 30 days before the expiration date.)

If you would like to publish the event to Event Grid 10 days before the expiration date,  you could try with Powershell to get all secrets that are near expiry, then send the event(see [Azure PowerShell samples for Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/powershell-samples).).

The [blog](https://www.felipeaugustol.com/post/checking-key-vault-items-near-to-expire-using-power-shell-and-publish-into-teams-channel?lang=en) shows how to monitor Key Vault secrets near or expired, note to instead `$DaysNearExpiration` with 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pamela . Is it a one time manual process to reduce $DaysNearExpiration from 30 to 10 ?

Comment: Sorry, it seems no method to change the near expiry time directly. You could only set it in your own code.